# How do you prevent Magento 2 from saving your cart between sessions

Tags: magento2

I'm having an issue in Magento 2 where a user will add items to their cart then logout. When the user comes back they add the items to their cart again and click proceed to checkout only to have the items duplicated. Is there a way to prevent this duplication from occuring?